# How to separate cpu bound task relying on local variables from async function with tokio?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I'm new to asynchronous programming and Rust. Basically, I'm doing something like.

```
fn func() {
    let task1 = tokio::spawn(async move || {
        let local_variable = ...;
        let res = heavy_computation(&local_variable);
        io(res).await;
    });
    let task2 = tokio::spawn(...);
}
```

The computation may block tokio runtime and `task2` may be stuck. I want to deal with this problem.

I've tried `rayon::scope` and `std::thread::scope`, since I don't want to clone the local variable. Like

```
fn func() {
    let task1 = tokio::spawn(async move || {
    let local_variable = ...;
    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        let (send, recv) = channel;
        s.spawn(|| {
            heavy_computation(&local_variable);
            send.send();
        });
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let res = recv.await.unwrap();
            io(res).await;
        });
    });
    let task2 = tokio::spawn(...);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to help. Guess it's because the nested runtimes are not the same one. Can't really figure out a good way.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid [`block_in_place`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.block_in_place.html)?

Comment: @cafce25 No, thread::scope and rayon::scope are the only ways I found the could capture local variables. Could block_in_place do that too?

Comment: @zkh Yes, it can. Theoretically, it is possible to design an async-suited `scope()` function, but I don't know if anyone did that :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a good [blog post](https://ryhl.io/blog/async-what-is-blocking/) by Tokio dev Alice Rhyl on handling blocking code in async.

The simplest option is to make it `Send`, instead of type `T` do `Arc<T>`.

```rust
let local_variable = std::sync::Arc::new(...);
let local_ref = local_variable.clone();
    
rayon::spawn(move || {
    let res = heavy_computation(&*local_ref);
    let _ = send.send(res);
}

let res = recv.await.expect("Panic in rayon::spawn")
```

But, if you really do want the shared with borrow (maybe that local comes from some context where it can't be `Arc`), it's a question of managing the lifetime without blocking in a bad way.

The problem is that you must ensure the thread isn't outliving your task, which scope is handling for you because it automatically joins the thread. This is what's causing the blocking most likely, though hard to say for certain because it looks like there's a typo in your second code block.

Based on the blog post, substituting `let task1 = tokio::spawn(` with [tokio::spawn_blocking](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) addresses your issue. The spawn blocking task handles waiting for the thread, rayon spawn, or scoped thread to exit without blocking your other task workers while the additional computation thread does its thing.

```rust
    tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
        let local_variable = 5;
        
        // Now, the implicit join doesn't matter, because this task is spawn_blocking
        let res = std::thread::scope(|s| {
            heavy_computation(&local_variable)
        });
    });
```